# How can i get separate textfield for card number, cvv and expiration date with Stripe

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, stripe-payments

I am using **Stripe** in my application for payment. For reference i have used https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios.

Here is my code snippet

```
let paymentCardTextField = STPPaymentCardTextField()

paymentCardTextField.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width:cardDetailsView.frame.width, height: cardDetailsView.frame.height)

paymentCardTextField.font = FontBold15
paymentCardTextField.delegate = self

cardDetailsView.addSubview(paymentCardTextField)
```

i have added textfield of type **STPPaymentCardTextField** to my view. From this implementation, i only have one textfield which have all three card params i.e. Card Number, CVV and Expiry date in one. But i want all three fields to be separate.

Refer my application UI:

[image]

Comment: Always post code, data, logs, error message, etc as text (not images) so they are searchable, and can be copied when answering. Please [edit] your question

Comment: make your own design and pass all fileds in STPCardParams() i.e card number, exp month, exp date and cvv

Comment: @AshleyMills Is it OK?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [BKMoneyKit](https://github.com/bkook/BKMoneyKit) library to create stripe like textField in your custom view, which already comes with validation methods. This approach will be better as you can make changes in your custom view whenever you want. And then after you can use stripe methods to create token or add card etc.

Comment: Isn't it possible with Stripe?

Comment: No, I didn't find any separate class for card number text field or cvv text field. -@TechValens